# Custom Form Layout Validation

Tags: forms, validation, kentico

I want to have my own validation flow, with custom layout and message.
By default, the validation from the form builder put all the error message beside the input field. And it will validate all fields at once after submit.

I want to validate field by field after submitting, and error message is displayed in the same place for all the input fields (beside the submit button/on top of the form).

Currently I'm trying custom form layout with "ASCX" type. Is it possible to do all the validation in the back-end code ".cs"?

Or I must inject java script at the custom form layout design in source mode?

Or there is any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML layout type you can place validation macros anywhere you need -> $$validation:FirstName$$

You can also specify a validation that executes without submitting the form - example -> http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/tweaking-kentico-(2)-unique-fields

Anyway, with the validation macro above you can move the error message wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your online form, go to Layout and enter your layout markup manually using HTML and the macros for form field values, labels and validation.  There you can specify where all your form elements will go on the form, even the button.

If you want to have custom CS for your validation of that form, you're better off creating a custom event handler for the form before insert.  See documentation below:

[Custom event handler](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/handling-object-events)
[Form Event handler](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-BizFormItemEvents)

```
using CMS;
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.OnlineForms;
using CMS.Helpers;

// Registers the custom module into the system
[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(CustomFormModule))]

public class CustomFormModule : Module
{
    // Module class constructor, the system registers the module under the name "CustomForms"
    public CustomFormModule()
        : base("CustomForms")
    {
    }

    // Contains initialization code that is executed when the application starts
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        base.OnInit();

        // Assigns a handler to the Insert.After event
        // This event occurs after the creation of every new form submission
        BizFormItemEvents.Insert.After += Insert_After;
    }

    private void Insert_After(object sender, CMS.OnlineForms.BizFormItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.TypeInfo.ObjectType.ToLower().Contains("bizform.codename"))
        {
            //do some work or form validation
        }
    }
}
```